# I want display Current user fields on visualforce page using field set.but my code is displaying only fields on form but not the value of current user

Tags: fieldsets

Controller :

```
public class AccountFieldSetController {
    public String queryString{get;set;}
    public List<User> accList{get;set;}
    public string user { get; set; }
    public User u { get; set; }
    public AccountFieldSetController(){

        u = new User();

        queryString = 'select id';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fld :SObjectType.User.FieldSets.Self_Service_My_Profile.getFields()) {
         queryString += ', ' + fld.getFieldPath();
        }
        queryString += ' from User limit 5';

        acclist = Database.query(queryString);
    }

}
```

VF Page:

```
             <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.User.fieldsets.Self_Service_My_Profile}" var="fieldValue">
             <apex:inputField value="{!u[fieldValue]}" required="{!OR(fieldValue.required, fieldValue.dbrequired)}"/>
             </apex:repeat>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Dynamic query" collapsible="false">
          <apex:outputText value="Query is: {!queryString}" />
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't query the current user, you get the first 5 users in your query and by doing `u = new User`, doesn't do anything at all. Also `List<User> accList` is a list of User, is that correct?

Try something like that, you should get at least your current user field based on your field set :

```
public AccountFieldSetController(){

    queryString = 'select id';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember fld :SObjectType.User.FieldSets.Self_Service_My_Profile.getFields()) {
     queryString += ', ' + fld.getFieldPath();
    }
    queryString += ' from User where id = \''+Userinfo.getUserId()+'\'';

    u = Database.query(queryString);
}
```